# Finding optimal threshold values between groups using ROC-analyses

Tags: roc, threshold

I am working on brain tumor data and I would like to be able to separate the uptake of a radioactive tracer in the tumors, depending on the tumor grade. Simplified explanation: Grade 2 tumors have the lowest uptake, grade 3 has higher uptake and grade 4 has highest uptake in general. ROC-analysis gives me a threshold of <1.99 (AUC:0.91, CI:0.82-1.00) for grade 2 tumors  and a threshold of >4.53 (AUC:0.89, CI:0.76-1.00) for grade 4 tumors. But how do I handle the grade 3 tumors? Does this imply that I can use an interval of 1.99-4.53 to define grade 3 tumors? If so, can I also calculate AUC and CI for this interval? Best, Anna